# Could any one explain why to load properties file from class path since we are able to load it from almost anywhere?

Tags: java

I mean, just by mentioning the .properties file path we can load it then why from CLASS-PATH?

Answer (score 1):

If it's packaged as part of your jar file (or another jar file; or a war or ear file), you can most easily load the properties file from the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm blind here, but perhaps calling the environment variable by its proper name, CLASS_PATH (underscore, not hyphen) would help.